# load custom config in twig IvoryCKEditorBundle Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, ckeditor4.x

I create my form like this:

```
$siteContent2Form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('cont_form_2', CKEditorType::class, $siteContent2, array(
        'label' => false,
        'config_name' => 'ckeditor_config_std',
))->getForm();
```

in twig:

```
{{ form_start(form_content_2) }}
{{ form_widget(form_content_2) }}
{{ form_end(form_content_2) }}
```

Is it possible to override the loaded config "ckeditor_config_std" and load another one in the template (twig)?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in Twig? Why not do it in the controller before passing the form object to Twig?

Comment: Because I have different templates using the same controller. The information which template is used comes from a database. If I change the controller I would change it for many different sites. But I need it only on a single page.

Comment: I see. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without creating a Twig extension. Here's what I found out:

---

I followed [Symfony's tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) to build a simple form with three fields. The `task` field is a CKEditor field:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->add('task', CKEditorType::class, [
        'config_name' => 'my_config',
        'config' => [
            'uiColor' => '#c0ffee',
        ],
    ])
    ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create task'])
    ->getForm();
```

Let's see what we have in Twig:

```
{{ dump(form) }}
```

```
FormView {#398 ▼
    +vars: array:24 [▶]
    +parent: null
    +children: array:3 [▼
        "task" => FormView {#403 ▶}
        "dueDate" => FormView {#405 ▶}
        "save" => FormView {#327 ▶}
    ]
    -rendered: false
    -methodRendered: false
}
```

See where the configuration options are (the `uiColor` config comes from PHP as seen above whereas the `toolbar` config comes from YAML configuration):

```
FormView {#398 ▼
    +children: array:3 [▼
        "task" => FormView {#403 ▼
            +vars: array:41 [▼
                "config" => array:2 [▼
                    "toolbar" => array:1 [▶]
                    "uiColor" => "#c0ffee"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `FormView` class doesn't seem to provide any methods for changing the vars: https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Form/FormView.html

You can neither use the `merge` filter because the `FormView` object will be converted into an array, and then you can't render the form:

```
{% set form = form|merge({}) %}

{{ dump(form) }}
```

```
array:3 [▼
    "task" => FormView {#403 ▶}
    "dueDate" => FormView {#405 ▶}
    "save" => FormView {#327 ▶}
]
```

---

You could create a simple Twig extension, something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('set_ckeditor_config', [$this, 'SetCKEditorConfig']),
        ];
    }

    public function SetCKEditorConfig($formView, $name, $value)
    {
        $formView->vars['config'][$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

And then in Twig:

```
{{ dump(form.task.vars.config) }}

{% do set_ckeditor_config(form.task, 'uiColor', '#bada55') %}
{% do set_ckeditor_config(form.task, 'height', 500) %}

{{ dump(form.task.vars.config) }}

{# You should render the form *after* calling the set_ckeditor_config function #}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

```
array:2 [▼
    "toolbar" => array:1 [▶]
    "uiColor" => "#c0ffee"
]

array:3 [▼
    "toolbar" => array:1 [▶]
    "uiColor" => "#bada55"
    "height" => 500
]
```

As you can see, this way you can modify single configuration options. This is not exactly what you asked, but it's close, right?

You can modify `SetCKEditorConfig` so that you set multiple configs at once. Then you would need to call `set_ckeditor_config` in Twig only once. That might be better if there are many configs that you want to change.

You can also try to modify the code so that you can choose different `config_name` (i.e. something else than `ckeditor_config_std` in your case). It seemed to be a more complex thing to do, so I gave up.

I hope this leads you on the right track.